# Why does my 'sessions' keep giving error?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-authenticator

I am trying to integrate the google authenticator app with my asp.net core web app but my Session in my home controller keeps giving errors. I'm looking for possible fixes.

using Google.Authenticator;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace QAService.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
public ActionResult Login()
{
return View();
}

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(FormCollection fc)

    {

        if (fc["username"] == "Admin" && fc["password"] == "Admin123")
        {
            Session["sampleid"] = fc["username"];
            return RedirectToAction("VerifyAuth");
        }
        else
        {
           return View();
        }
    }
    public ActionResult VerifyAuth()

    {
        if (Session["sampleid"] != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
    string key = "test123!@@)(*";

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult VerifyAuth(FormCollection fc)
    {
        if (Session["sampleid"] == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Admin_Login");
        }
        var token = fc["passcode"];
        TwoFactorAuthenticator tfa = new TwoFactorAuthenticator();
        string UserUniqueKey = (Convert.ToString(Session["sampleid"]) + key);

        bool isValid = tfa.ValidateTwoFactorPIN(UserUniqueKey, token);

        if (isValid)

        {

            Session["id"] = Convert.ToString(Session["sampleid"]);



            return RedirectToAction("Myprofile");

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Login");

    }

    public ActionResult AdminQR()

    {

        if (Session["sampleid"] != null)
        {

            TwoFactorAuthenticator tfa = new TwoFactorAuthenticator();

            string UserUniqueKey = (Convert.ToString(Session["sampleid"]) + key);

            Session["UserUniqueKey"] = UserUniqueKey;

            var setupInfo = tfa.GenerateSetupCode("Google Auth Test", Convert.ToString(Session["sampleid"]), UserUniqueKey, 300, 300);

            ViewBag.BarcodeImageUrl = setupInfo.QrCodeSetupImageUrl;

            ViewBag.SetupCode = setupInfo.ManualEntryKey;

            return View();
        }

        else

        {

            return RedirectToAction("Login");

        }

    }
    public ActionResult Myprofile()
    {
        if (Session["id"] != null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
           return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try `Request.Form["username"]`